# Log file extract data and append back same line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, snort

I have a snort.rule file, I need to extract cve numbers followed by reference key from the line and append them back in **msg** field of the same line inside flower brackets, below is the old log.

> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference:arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)

Required output is below, bold ones are the new changes,

> alert udp $HOME_NET 1900 -> any any (msg:"ET INFO UPnP Discovery Search Response vulnerable UPnP device 2 **{cve,2012-5958 cve,2012-5959}**"; content:"Intel SDK for UPnP devices"; pcre:"/^Server\x3a[^\r\n]*Intel SDK for UPnP devices/mi"; reference: /infosec/blog/2013/01/29; reference: arch/UPnP-arch-DeviceArchitecture-v1.1.pdf; reference:cve,2012-5958; reference:cve,2012-5959;sid:2016303; rev:4;)

I am able to extract the CVE numbers, but appending back I am not getting

```
cat /tmp/snort.rule | grep -o -E -e 'sid:[^;]+' -e 'reference:cve,[^;]+'
```

Comment: Please edit your input and output so the changes are more obvious without having to scroll

Answer (score 1):

Well you can try this out, copy this in a shell file and run this, you can store the output to new file. 
`awk -F\; '
  {
    for ( i = 1 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) {
      if ( $i ~ "msg" )
        a = i
      if ( $i ~ "reference:cve," ) {
        b = $i
        sub ( ".*:" , "" , b )
        c = c " " b 
        }
      }
    sub ( ".$" , "{" c "\"}" , $a )
  }
1' /tmp/snort.rule`